# Can you use ViewComponents with Razor pages?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have come across what appears to be a limitation with using *ViewComponent's* in **ASP.NET Core 2.0**.

We have a *ViewComponent* that works absolutely perfectly when invoked from a layout page. When we invoke the same *ViewComponent* from a Razor page we get the following error.

**The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type <viewcomponenttype> but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type <parentpagetype>**

The *ViewComponent* seems to expect the model type of the parent *Razor* page to be passed, rather than the model type defined for the *ViewComponent*.

I haven't come across any examples of a *ViewComponent* being used from a *Razor* page, they only seem to be used from layout pages (which don't have models).

Can someone give me a definitive yes or no to the question: can you use *ViewComponent's* within a *Razor* page, and if so, how?

Comment: yes, they can be used the same way, can you post some code ? what is the model you defined in the .cshtml file and what is the model you return in the invoke method of the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, I made a quick example with a hilarious naming.

View component class - Sample**ViewView**Component :)

```
namespace NetCoreUI.ViewComponents
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class SampleViewViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(Models.TestVm testVm)
        {
            testVm.TestName = "Changing name from ViewComponent.";

            return View(testVm);
        }
    }
}
```

Default view for this View component:

```
@model NetCoreUI.Models.TestVm

<h1>This is viewcomponent.</h1>

<p>@Model.TestId</p>
<p>@Model.TestName</p>
```

My Razor page code with not much going on:

```
namespace NetCoreUI.Pages.Motorcycle
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

    public class SampleModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And finally a Razor page view where I invoke my ViewComponent:

```
@page
@model NetCoreUI.Pages.Motorcycle.SampleModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Sample";
}

<h2>Sample</h2>

<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("SampleView", new { testVm = new Models.TestVm() })
</div>
```

I chose to invoke my ViewComponent with a simple new TestVm() class, but this class could be subset inside SampleModel and you could invoke your View Component with that instance of the correct class - the correct class be the one your ViewComponent is referencing.

This is a really simple example, I'm not sure how your app is structured or perhaps there's a different issue.

Comment: I've taken your example and worked it for my own specific requirements and it all seems to work. Thanks for the reply I appreciate it :)

Comment: Do you have to use a model with the ViewComponent?

Answer (score 4):

Additionally on the answer by Iztoksson, if you are well versed in using tag helpers, you may use it in invoking the ViewComponent

```
<div>    
   <vc:SampleView testVm = "new { testVm = new Models.TestVm() }"></vc:SampleView>
</div>
```

although you have to register the viewcomponents tag in the

> ViewImports.cshtml

file and add the following line to the existing code:

```
@addTagHelper *, RazorPages
```